# Additional Form submit button with redirection

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, form-submit

I have added additional submit button on node create page via form_alter:

```
$form['check_data'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#value' => 'Check',
    '#validate' => array('node_form_validate'),
    '#submit' => array('node_form_submit', 'custom_redirect'),
);
```

So the button now validates the form and saves the node, but it doesn't redirect it afterwards:

```
function custom_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/%nid/check';
}
```

Any ideas how to redirect it after submission?

Comment: Triead adding drupal_goto()? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x

Comment: Hi Milan, yes I have. I both cases it just saves the node.

Comment: To me happened once that not even drupal_goto() worked so I had to do redirection with php header function. Not much of the solution, I know...but in despaired moments...

Answer (score -1):

in `_form_alter` add the following:

```
$form['actions']['check_data']['#submit'][] = 'custom_redirect';
```

and/or check does `form_state` have `nid` and use it from there, like

```
$form_state['nid'], $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/' . $form_state['nid'] . '/check';
```